# No results obtained with JQuery $.getJSON in the PhoneGap environment

Tags: php, jquery, cordova

Here is my funciton:

```
function getEmployeeList() {
alert("hello world3!");
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php', function(data) {
alert("hello world4!");
    $('#employeeList li').remove();
    employees = data.items;
    $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
        $('#employeeList').append('<li><a href="employeedetails.html?id=' + employee.id + '">' +
                '<img src="pics/' + employee.picture + '"/>' +
                '<h4>' + employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.lastName + '</h4>' +
                '<p>' + employee.title + '</p>' +
                '<span class="ui-li-count">' + employee.reportCount + '</span></a></li>');
    });
    $('#employeeList').listview('refresh');
});
}
```

When the page is ready, it will run this function, however, nothing is appended.
I have tested, all php can return correct format. What wrongs?? Please please help me...

Comment: Check the output with your browsers developers tools. Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: How/where are you calling this function?

Comment: here: $('#employeeListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
 getEmployeeList();
});

Comment: actually i follow everything from http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/

Comment: Do what @JanDragsbaek said - also make sure `serviceURL` is on the same domain as where you are testing.

Comment: and what would `alert(data)` show if you did that inside the success function?

Comment: i can see "helloworld3" but cannot see "helloworld4"

Comment: could you post JSON data returned by `getemployees.php`?

Comment: http://www.smartmobisys.com/fyp2012/fyp2012c/OSS/getemployees.php

Comment: @red23jordan: I'm guessing this page (your code) is not on `smartmobisys.com`, so you are being blocked by the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the external host (in my case was mysite.localhost) in PhoneGap.plist under the "ExternalHosts" key.

Answer (score 0):

I presume `serviceURL` is not on the same domain.
In that case you add `callback=?` in the end, and jQuery does some magic:

```
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php?callback=?', function(data) {
...
```

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: That is if the `serviceURL` supports JSONP in the first place.